# Asymptotic bound with square-roots

Tags: asymptotics, radicals

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be two increasing functions of $n$ such that:

$$ f \leq g + O(\sqrt{g}) + O(\sqrt{f}) $$

Is it true that:

$$ f \leq g + O(\sqrt{g}) $$

? If not, then what would be a good asymptotic upper bound on $f$?

NOTE: the asymptotic behavior is when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Where are you considering your asymptotics? $0$, $\infty$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ClementC.it is $\infty$. Fixed.

Comment: Fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: if $f(n) \to \infty$ yes, if $f(n) \to 0$, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not hold; for instance, take the following, where the asymptotics are taken around $+\infty$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x}, \qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}
$$
Then $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x^3} + O(x^{-3/2}) +  O(x^{-1/2}) = O(x^{-1/2})  = O(\sqrt{f(x)})$$
but we do **not** have $f(x) \leq x^{-3} + O(x^{-3/2}) = O(x^{-3/2})$. You can adapt this example to other situations: you cannot get a better bound only in terms of $g$, since if the "relevant" upper bound from the first line if $f=O(\sqrt{f})$ then $g$ and $f$ can be arbitrarily unrelated.

---

**Following the clarification from the OP:**
Now, assuming further that $f\nearrow \infty$ and $g$ is non-decreasing: $\sqrt{f} = o(f)$, so that we must have $f \leq g + O(\sqrt{g})$. Indeed, dividing by $\sqrt{f}$, we get
$$
\sqrt{f} \leq \frac{g}{\sqrt{f}} + O\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{f}}\right) + O(1)
$$
and since the LHS goes to infinity, so does the RHS. this implies in turn that $\sqrt{g}=o(g)$: otherwise, we do not have $g\to\infty$, so by monotonicity $g$ converges to a finite limit, and thus so does $\sqrt{g}$: the RHS does not go to infinity.

It follows that $\sqrt{g}=o(g)$, and therefore $g\nearrow\infty$; and we also get that $g = \Omega(f)$. Indeed, otherwise we would have $g=o(f)$ (not quite, but for a subsequence at least -- ignoring this detail), so that we would get, from the beginning:
$$
f \leq o(f) + O(\sqrt{f}) = o(f)
$$
which is impossible. Finally, this means that $\sqrt{g} = \Omega(\sqrt{f})$, and therefore
$$
f \leq g + O(\sqrt{g}).
$$

Comment: Note that there may be some hope under an additional constraint on $f,g$... for instance, $\lim_{\infty} f = \infty$.

Comment: OK, but what if the functions are increasing? (Sorry for the misunderstanding. I come from computational complexity theory, where functions are almost always increasing and the asymptotics are when $n\to \infty$).

Comment: I come from there too :) (but for approximation algorithms or error probabilities, the asymptotics can be taken when $\varepsilon \to 0$)

Comment: $f + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{f}) = \mathcal{O}(f)$ is true except if $f \to 0$, nothing complicated here

Comment: @user1952009 But the goal, as i understand it, was to obtain a tight-ish upper bound depending on $g$, not $f$...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I updated my answer... did that in a stream-of-thought sort of way, so it may be slightly messy (but hopefully correct).

Comment: @Clement C. if $f + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{f}) = \mathcal{O}(f)$ then $f = \mathcal{O}(|f| + |\sqrt{f}|)$ and because we know $f + |\sqrt{f}| = \mathcal{O}(|g| + |\sqrt{g}|)$ (from his 1st formula) we are done. (the $\mathcal{O}$ formulas should be read from left to right : reading "something dominated by, up to a multiplicative constant" each time we read a $\mathcal{O}$)